# How to Convert JSON to Array following structure below

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I fetch data from `firebase realtime` database data and passing data google spreadsheets. I struggle data map in json object.

any one help me for solve this request.

My firebase realtime database structure: https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/users.json

```
{
"4rjF1iwudEXEevtzEoGwDrEtEpI3":
   {
     "agg1":true,
     "agg2":true,
     "category":"Solo"
   },

"8I71pW0JXqflBQf5YMBdJ0kv8F13":
   {
     "agg1":true,
     "agg2":true,
     "category":"Trio"
   }
}
```

I tried this map.

```
var itemArray = [];
  var valueArray = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index) => {
    itemArray.push(key);
    itemArray.push(data[key]);
    valueArray[index] = itemArray;
    itemArray = [];
  });
```

Comment: what structure do you want to end up with?

Comment: add your input/users.json data.

Comment: As far I understand you only want values in array like this :- [
  [
    {
      "agg1": true,
      "agg2": true,
      "category": "Solo"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "agg1": true,
      "agg2": true,
      "category": "Trio"
    }
  ]
],                                                                                                                           just remove itemArray.push(key).

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve. Ideally include in the code above an example of the output you expect/want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values(data)` insted of `Object.keys(data)`. like this

```
var itemArray = [];
  var valueArray = [];
  Object.values(data).forEach((value, index) => {
    itemArray.push(value);
  });
```

Your code should also work but you have added irreverent lines remove it like this.

```
var itemArray = [];
  var valueArray = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index) => {
    itemArray.push(data[key]);
  });
```

Comment: why downvoting my answer? tell me the problem

Comment: `Object.values(data)` already returns an array of values, why to loop through and push each value into a new array?

Comment: yeah, you are right but the question is not clear so I thought this is what he wanted to do.